# Finding the consecutive pairs of the values in a row and then operating on them in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame in python like:

```
item  Value

abc   3
xyz   5
pqr   7
abc   3
pqr   7
abc   5
xyz   5
```

Now I want to add the first occurrence of any value and the second occurrence of that item's value in pairs,
so the output should be like:-

```
item  Value

abc   6
abc   8
xyz   10
pqr   14
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: i have tried to iterate through the data frame and comparing them with the unique values in the dataframe have already obtained then grouping them  but only able to group like that

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a question for logic than pandas but since you asked in pandas, there is a quick way to do this:

```
df['value_to_add'] = df.sort_values('item').groupby('item').shift(-1)
df.dropna(inplace=True) 
df['value'] = df.value + df.value_to_add
df.drop('value_to_add', inplace=True, axis=1)
```